# How can i move a file with existing one in C#

Tags: io

How can i move a file in C#, from one path to another path.
I don't want to copy that file, in the condition of copying, it is working fine for me.But i want to move that file don't want to copy.
it should be move from one path to another path and overwrite the existing one.

I have tried below code it is working fine for copy.

System.IO.File.Copy(file, targetFilePath,true);

but i want same functionality for moving a file

Please help me out.

Comment: Language? Attempts? Anything?

Comment: On which operating system, with which libraries, with which programming language and implementation???? What code did you try? On what filesystems? Same filesystem for source or destination?

Comment: @Quirliom if you are not getting the question please let it be...but please don't give the -ve points because i am new user... :)

Comment: @ShrutiSingh Didn't downvote, but the original version of this question did deserve one.

Comment: @Quirliom but i got the down vote, because of this i can not post more questions... :(

Answer (score 0):

There is move methiod. Please check link above: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx

Comment: It will move the file from one path to another one but i want to overwrite the existing one.